# Change image at certain times of day using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've looked around and cobbled together a script that will change an image on a WordPress site depending whether it is morning, day or evening.

A morning image shows between the hours of 5am and 12 noon.
A day image shows between the hours of 12 noon and 9pm.
A night image shows if the time is neither of them.

I am stuck on two things.

1) Currently for any time starting 12:xx the evening images shows rather than the day one. Then at 13 the day one shows. How I do I make it so that bang on 12 noon the images change?

2) How do I set the code to run every 60 seconds? Currently if a time change occurs the correct image doesn't display unless you refresh / reload

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var day_night = new Date().getHours();{
        if (day_night > 5 && day_night < 12){
            document.getElementById("gilidimage").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://morning-image-here.png')";
        } else
            if (day_night > 12 && day_night < 21){
                document.getElementById("gilidimage").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://day-image-here.png')";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("gilidimage").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://night-image-here.png')";
            }
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

My first ever post / question so be honest but not brutal :)

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Why the `{` after `.getHours();`

Comment: It's the first bit of code I've written so I got over excited

Answer (score 2):

to get it to change at noon this line `if (day_night > 5 && day_night < 12){` needs to be set to `<=` like this `if (day_night > 5 && day_night <= 12){`

to get it to update every 60 seconds, you can wrap the whole thing in a function and the use `setInterval` to run the function every 60 seconds here is some updated code that should work for you

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
   $(document).ready(function(){
   function check_image() {
      var day_night = new Date().getHours();
      if (day_night > 5 && day_night <= 12) {
        $("#gilidimage").css('background-image',"url('http://morning-image-here.png')");
      }
      else if (day_night > 12 && day_night < 21) {
             $("#gilidimage").css('background-image',"url('http://day-image-here.png')");
        }
       else {
          $("#gilidimage").css('background-image',"url('http://night-image-here.png')");
       } 
   }
  setInterval(check_image,60000);
});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: this works if you remove the quotes from `check_image`.

[working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/phlare/5xbmw2mc/)

Comment: Thanks for the help. As always it's something simple... but only if you have the knowledge ;) In layman's terms what is that line saying now? For any time that is greater than 5 but less than or equal to 12 show the morning image? Thanks

Comment: @TimTJSwarbrick yes you are correct, it has to be greater than 5 and less than OR EQUAL to 12

Answer (score 0):

```js
setInterval(function () {
        var Today = new Date();
        var H = Today.getHours();
        if (H >= 5 && H < 12 ) {
            console.log("morning");
        }
        else if (H >= 12  && H < 21) {
            console.log("afternoon");
        }
        else {
            console.log("night");
        }
    }, 3000);//repet time (ms)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```